# How to save custom data to PHAsset using Photos.Framework

Tags: ios, swift, video, phasset, phphotolibrary

Im using Photos framework to save and retrieve videos from the device's album.

While saving my videos, i would like to add some custom data, like: id, name, description, and so on...
and to get all this data while retrieving it back from the album.

is that possible ?

The code I'm using to save the videos is:

```
    func saveVideo(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> ()) {

        if assetCollection == nil {
             return   // If there was an error upstream, skip the save.
        }

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: url)
            let assetPlaceholder = assetChangeRequest?.placeholderForCreatedAsset
            let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection)
            albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([assetPlaceholder] as NSFastEnumeration)
        }, completionHandler: {
            saved, error in
            completionHandler(saved,error)
        })
    }
```